# Как упорядочить регистры при использовании массива с данными типа String

Tags: java, реестр

Скажем есть массив с типом String, в котором есть текст и у него разные регистры,  к примеру `"КОЛЯ пуШкин"`
Как правильно реализовать процесс, который упорядочит регистр букв, чтобы было первая буква была заглавная, а остальные прописные

Парочку примеров:

Из `"кОЛЯ Пушкин" -> "Коля Пушкин"`

Из `"ПОбеда" -> "Победа"`

Из `"АлеКСей" -> "Алексей"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        String s = "КОЛЯ пуПкин";
    String[] array = s.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        String s1 = array[i];
        array[i] = s1.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s1.substring(1, s1.length()).toLowerCase();
    }
    System.out.println(array[0] + " " + array[1]);
```

Ну, например, так. Это алгоритм для отдельной строки, можете применить его для каждой строки из массива. Суть в том, что первый символ делаем принудительно в верхнем кейсе, а остальное в нижнем. Потом склеиваем и вуаля.